# How to setup communication between ASP.NET CORE Web and WebAPI containers for AKS and Helm

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I have two projects, one in ASP.NET Core MVC in one container, the other in ASP.NET Core WebAPI in a separate container, both are using Azure Kubernetes Service and Helm.

The MVC project makes calls to the WebAPI project. It works locally by using `localhost`.

My question is how to set it up so that it works on AKS and accepts public request.

Comment: Some details are missing here to give you an accurate answer. How are the 2 projects installed on AKS? Are they running in separate pods? If this is the case, you will need a k8s service object that will allow them to access each other, and route the requests through the k8s dns instead of localhost.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I just need a Hello World example that shows best practices uisng AKS.

Comment: Using "localhost" locally is not a must. Since I am new to AKS and HELM. I am open to the best practices.

Comment: This is not an AKS or Helm question, it has to do with the way kubernetes routes communication within the cluster. You can follow this guide to understand more on how kubernetes implements this stuff - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/

Comment: Thanks for the link. It reminds me of this link. How can it be used with an ASP.NET CORE app, which can runs both locally and on AKS, described on my OP.

Comment: Again, in order to answer that - I need to understand I need to see how your app is deployed to k8s. In general - if your app has a service object selecting the pods of your app, another app in the same namespace should be able to resolve the name of the service and send requests to its pods.

Comment: I am new to K8s, and AKS, I wish I can answer your questions

Answer (score 2):

You can read this [document](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-networking-guide-beginners.html) which shows you the network in Kubernetes that communicate be between containers in the same pod, or in the same node but different pods, or in the different pods and different nodes. And Kubernetes usually use the service for each deployment to communicate between pods.

It's simple to achieve. You just need to create two images for your applications and use the images to create the deployment. Make sure what is the service for each deployment. In your code, when you want to connect to another pod of the deployment, you can directly connect it with the service of the deployment.

Here I show you a simple plan:

```
deployment: frontend -> ASP.NET Core MVC, service: frontend-service
deployment: backend -> ASP.NET Core WebAPI, service: backend-service
```

Within the frontend container, you can connect the backend container like this, I just use the shell command to make the example:

```
curl http://backend-service
```

It means you just need to connect the container you expect with its service.

Helm just use the [chart](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/) to manage all the things for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and links, which are helpful. But I still cannot apply them to ASP.NET Core app without code. I need to google it maybe.

Comment: @Pingpong So what is the thing you still confused with?

Comment: I need to have a proper read first. But first, how to apply these onto ASP.NET CORE in calling one project from another, and running it both locally and on AKS. One of the issues is how to and where to define urls for both projects.

Comment: Thanks. I need to connect to different container programmatically, install of using `curl http://backend-service`. But it is interesting to know that I can login to the container and try that, if I am not mis-understanding. But how to login to the container, I have to find out.

Comment: @Pingpong You can use the command `kubectl exec -it podName -- bash` if it's a Linux container. You can also connect inside your code, not only `curl` command, this is just an example.

Comment: @Pingpong So does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found the solution yet.

Comment: @Pingpong What do you mean? The solution for connecting another container through the code? Which code?